# Listbox Data & Image not showing in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox

I am totally new on Windows Phone 8.I want to display Image and text together in listbox. I use the flowing code to do that but it shows nothing in my design view . Then I debug this code it shows nothing except page title.  Please help me .

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:UI="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"
x:Class="Masala.Infotainment"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="images/home_bg.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="Page Title"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox Name="mahin" Width="450">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Margin="8"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Source="images/cc.png"
                                Width="100"
                                Height="100" />
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="MAHIN"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You forgot to set `ListBox`'s `ItemSource`, didn't you?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Grid` instead of StackPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you want to achieve your task to show image and text in listbox? there 2 ways.

1. Data binding, in this case your listbox's ItemsSource property will be bonded to some List/enumerable. and the properties are binded to the image and textblock control.
2. adding items directly to the listbox in xaml(or it can be done in code behind)

from your code sample you have created only the listbox item template. which will not show anything. you need to create item source and bind that to the listbox.

if you have static list and want to add/show them in xaml. here is how you can do that.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" width="420">
<ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Assets/book1.png"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="Book 1" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Assets/book2.png"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="Book 2" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

And below is full listbox example of bindig the list.

Your listBox xaml in gird.

```
<ListBox Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,160,0,0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Make}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Add a new class in your project...
    public class Car
    {
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }

```
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

add following code in your xaml page code behind(page constructor)

```
 List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();

        var car = new Car() { Make = "Toytoa", Model = "Corola", Image = "Assets/applogo240.png" };
        cars.Add(car);
        car = new Car() { Make = "Honda", Model = "Acord", Image = "Assets/applogo240.png" };
        cars.Add(car);
        car = new Car() { Make = "Honda", Model = "Civic", Image = "Assets/applogo240.png" };
        cars.Add(car);

        ///Bind list to listbox..
        lstView.ItemsSource = cars;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways You can use:

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"></Image>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

C#:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}


 Article article1 = new Article() { Name = "name1", ImagePath = "path of image 1" };
 Article article2 = new Article() { Name = "name2", ImagePath = "path of image 2" };

 var articles = new List<Article>();
 articles.Add(article1);
 articles.Add(article2);

 lstView.DataContext = articles;
```

Comment: Dont understand . Where should i create object of Article ?

Comment: where you want to load data at that event you can create Object. e.g. onNavigatedTo/PageLoaded/Button_Click etc.